# Is it necessary to use virtualenv from github project I downloaded?

Tags: github, virtualenv

I used to download package or github project with no management.

Everything just straight into my dir and therefore many of them can't work correctly

### Then I realized I need to use virtualenv or something that help me manage my package

Here is the problem, I am trying to run a project with plenty of package. ex: transformer,torch...

Is it ok that after i download a project and then use virtualenv to manage the package?

after git clone cd to this dir and use virtualenv -p python to create the environment

or is there a better method to solve this issue? thanks for answering

PS:not native English speaker. my grammar or vocabulary might seems wired

Comment: "*Is it ok that after i download a project and then use virtualenv to manage the package?"* Yes. Not only it's ok — it's the best practice. Not necessary with `cd dir && virtualenv -p python` — there're many ways to manage virtual environments (like [tag:virtualenvwrapper] and [tag:pyenv-virtualenv]).

Comment: thanks for replying, the reason i asked this issue is because i tried to run a project form github using virtualenv and it somehow just broke

I wasn't sure whether it is because i am not suppose to use virtualenv in the project or what. Now i got my answer thanks